# How to get executable phar command from the PHP source working?

Tags: php, command-line, phar

I want to be able to work with `phar` command line tool (on Debian Linux) like described on [this manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/phar/).

What I've done so far:

1. downloaded the [PHP PHAR source folder](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/phar/phar);
2. moved it to `/usr/share/`;
3. altered the first line of the `phar.php` from `#!/usr/local/bin/php` to `#!/usr/bin/php` (path to the PHP symlink -> to the PHP executable file);
4. created a symlink `phar` to `/usr/share/phar/phar.php`.

Now `phar help` returns an error:

```
# phar help
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'manifest cannot be larger than 100 MB in phar "/usr/share/phar/phar.php"' in /usr/share/phar/phar.php:48
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/phar/phar.php(48): Phar::mapPhar()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/phar/phar.php on line 48
```

What am I doing wrong? How to get it working?

Thx

Comment: It works! S. [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373638/how-to-get-where-to-obtain-the-php-phar-command-line-tool#comment21793827_15373638) to the question "[How to get / where to obtain the PHP phar command line tool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373638/how-to-get-where-to-obtain-the-php-phar-command-line-tool)".

Answer (score 0):

Probably a corrupted phar file.  Try download it again.